# Run rake in project built with cmake

Tags: cmake, fortran

I'm trying to build a fortran project that uses Fruit for unit tests. Essentially, I have a fortran module source file which contains some subroutines named test_something, and then I want to run a Rakefile which calls Fruit to generate a fortran program source file which will run all the tests. Fruit uses rake for this purpose, so not using rake isn't really an option for me.

I've included these commands to tell cmake to expect these files to be generated:

```
set_source_files_properties(fruit_driver_gen.f90 PROPERTIES GENERATED true)
set_source_files_properties(fruit_basket_gen.f90 PROPERTIES GENERATED true)
```

Then I have a custom command to run rake:

```
add_custom_command(    
   OUTPUT fruit_driver_gen.f90 fruit_basket_gen.f90
   COMMAND rake gen
   DEPENDS Rakefile)
```

The Rakefile is just a file that needs to be copied over to the folder where the custom command is executed, but whith DEPENDS it's registered as a target, so I try adding it as a custom target like this:

```
add_custom_target(Rakefile SOURCES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Rakefile}")
```

When I run cmake, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at tests/CMakeLists.txt:20 (add_custom_target):
  Cannot find source file:

    ~/Fruit_example/tests/Rakefile}

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp
  .hxx .in .txx
```

Am I doing something completely wrong? Is there a more elegant way to achive what I want? I'm essentially trying to make cmake copy and run a script to generate some output, and I guess I can't be the only one trying to do that, even if using Fortran and Fruit is perhaps not that common.

Comment: And by the way, I tried to add the tag Fruit, but I don't have sufficient reputation. Anyone who does, feel free to add the tag.

Comment: I'm not familiar with any of the tools you mention here except CMake, but the `DEPENDS` argument need not be a target - it can be a file.  This file can itself be the output of another `add_custom_command` if required.  So if "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Rakefile" always exists, just try removing the `add_custom_target` and having `add_custom_command(... DEPENDS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Rakefile)`.  If you need to copy the Rakefile to its location first, you can add in the same CMakeLists.txt something like: contd...

Comment: `add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Rakefile COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different <Rakefile from path> ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Rakefile)`